# Whether this vector norm proposition is true? $ \vert x_i \vert \ge \vert y_i \vert \Rightarrow \Vert X \Vert \ge \Vert Y \Vert$

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

Whether this vector norm proposition is true?

$ \vert x_i \vert \ge \vert y_i \vert \Rightarrow \Vert X \Vert \ge \Vert Y \Vert$
where $X, Y \in \mathbb R ^n$

Is it true for all kinds of norms?

I've attempted some norms below and it is obviously true for them:

1. $\Vert X \Vert _p = \left ( \sum \limits_{i = 1} ^{n} \vert x_i
       \vert ^p \right ) ^{1/p}, p \in [1, + \infty)$
2. $\Vert X \Vert _{\infty} = \max \limits_{1 \le i \le n} \vert x_i
       \vert $
3. In case $n = 1,$ $\Vert X \Vert = \Vert x \Vert = \Vert 1 \Vert \vert x \vert$

Comment: obvious if you just write down the definition. At least true for the standard norm and the sup norm.

Comment: What about the other norms?

Comment: there are infinitely many norms on $\mathbb{R^n}$. Specify which norm and show what you have attempted

Comment: If $x,y$ are linearly dependent the implication holds. If they are independent, let $A$ be an invertible linear transformation that maps them to $e_1,2e_2$, respectively. Then $\left\|x\right\|_{\text{example norm}}=\left\|Ax\right\|_2$ is one of the norms that your instructor is talking about. You can obtain $A$ by completing $x,y/2,a_3,...,a_n$ to a basis. Putting them as columns of a matrix and taking inverse of that matrix.

Comment: You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you one of my students? I thought about this today in class, and snarkily remarked that if this was false I'd give back my degree. I shouldn't have, because I was wrong!

Suppose that $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent vectors, and satisfy your hypothesis. Since they span a plane, we may as well assume we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now we can go ahead and make a norm that has $||x|| = 1$ and $||y|| = 2$. Since these vectors are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can extend this linearly to a norm on the whole plane. It is by definition homogeneous, only $0$ for the $0$ vector, and since we have defined it to be a linear map, it satisfies the triangle inequality. However, it has $|x_i| < |y_i|$ for both $i$.

The triangle inequality may require some further comments, so let's make them. Let $p = a_1x + a_2y$ and $q = b_1x + b_2y$. This is possibly since $x$ and $y$ are a basis. Now $$||p + q|| = ||(a_1+b_1)x + (a_2+b_2)y| = (a_1+b_1) + 2(a_2+b_2)$$

But also $||p|| = a_1 + 2a_2$ and $||q|| = b_1 + 2 b_2$, so it turns out that here we have $$||p + q|| = ||p|| + ||q|| \leq ||p|| + ||q||$$ so the triangle inequality holds.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a student though I like mathematics :( Your answer provides a new perspective  :) but there is still an issue :  A norm should be non-negative, however if $\begin{pmatrix} a_1,  & a_2, \\ b_1, & b_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -1, & -1 \\ -1, & -1 \end{pmatrix} $ then the result is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Define a norm on $\Bbb R^2$ by $$||(x,y)||=|x|+|x-y|.$$

Comment: This norm doesn't prove that the implication is false for the vectors $(3,2)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: It proved if we use $(4, 3)$ and $(3, 0)$. Then $\Vert (4,3) \Vert =|4|+|4 - 3| = 5,$ but $\Vert (3,0) \Vert =|3|+|3 - 0| = 6$

Comment: @JiongjiongLi I know. I am just point out that even for proving the negation of the implication in the weakest form possible (one fixed norm, one fixed pair of vectors), this answer is incomplete. So, you chose, among the two answers, the worst possible.

Comment: OK I also accepct @alfred-yerger 's answer since his method is very enlightening.